# To create package in ssis for xml file and parse it and get required columns in the table sql

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

I am working on SSIS. My question is I want to write a ssis package to parse XML file and the output should store in the database.
what I did:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcEum.png)
in this package, I haven't written any code for parsing.

here is the output I am getting
[enter image description here][2]
In the output, I am getting only the header values from 
XML file but I need to read the data which is the each header too

actual output should be like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFRwb.png)

here the XML file data:

```
 Meter MediaType="900 MHz" ObservesDaylightSavings="true" TimeZoneOffset="300" Timezone="(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)" TimeZoneIndex="11" Location="" SdpIdent="" AccountName="" AccountIdent="" RemovalDate="" InstallDate="2013-05-01 20:28:09" Description="" MeterType="REX" SerialNumber="03310266" IsActive="true" MeterName="03310266" MeterIrn="21"/>   

<IntervalSpec Multiplier="0.1" Direction="Received" UOM="kWh" TimestampEnd="2013-08-09 00:00:00" TimestampStart="2013-08-02 00:15:00" Channel="2" Interval="15"/>

<Reading TimeStamp="2013-08-02 00:15:00" RawReading="0"/>

<Reading TimeStamp="2013-08-02 00:30:00" RawReading="0"/>

<Reading TimeStamp="2013-08-02 00:45:00" RawReading="0"/>

<Reading TimeStamp="2013-08-02 01:00:00" RawReading="0"/>
```

Can anyone help?